# Fill array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got a trouble here! I have a function that verify an XML file for errors. If the function finds it, I save the errors in one Array to print the errors after the successfull (non error) results.

But to print the errors, for each loop, I print a div, showing the errors, but these DIV's must be printed at all and showing all errors found! I dont know if that was very clear, but i'll show a bit of code to help the understanding.

Here, I put inside the array all the errors

```
$value = the results inside the error search on the XML
foreach($values as $founderrors){
            $founderrors= array($valores);
            }
```

Ok, now here i have this:

```
 if ($values["erro"]==true) {

            $divErro1 = '<div> lololol </div>';

$erros = array($divErro1,$divErro2);

           foreach($valores as $testeste){
            $testeste = array($erros);
            }
         return true;
```

That is where i fill the "Div errors"

And down the code i have this:

```
print_r($testeste);
```

To print the array!

But it only shows the last "Error Div"! I think he's replacing the found divs and showing the last one only, when i need to print all divs containing all errors. Ah, just ignore the content of the Div, there's another code inside it to show the respective error.

Could anyone give me a help? Thanks a lot! =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not filling your arrays correctly, have a look at

http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

to learn more about arrays.

For example:

```
$testeste = array($erros);
```

Here your overriding whatever `$testeste` was before, with `array($erros)`. So you're not actually collecting anything.

If you want to collect data in an array, you'll have to add to the array, like for example

```
$testeste[] = $erros;
```

or

```
array_push($testeste, $erros);
```

Comment: Hi Yoshi :D! Thanks for helping but if i use the [] the PHP returns Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in...

Comment: @Armando Freire Then `$testeste` is initialized as a string. Can you please updated your question, and include more of your code?

Comment: Hi Yoshi, my `$testeste` var is initialized as the `$erro` wich is filled by `$divErro1` , That's all i got! :D

Comment: I adapted the provided solution and now it's working! I also took a look at the Array documentation! Ty =)

Answer (score 0):

You can populate arrays using []. For example:

```
if ($values["erro"]==true) {

$divErro1 = '<div> lololol </div>';

$erros = array($divErro1,$divErro2);

foreach($valores as $testeste){
    $testeste[] = $erros;
}

return true;
```

Comment: Hi Klaus, tyvm for helping but if i use the [] the PHP returns Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in...